# What is meant by strictly in this statement?

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers

> If $n$ is prime, then $n$ is not divisible by any prime number between 1 and $\sqrt{n}$ *strictly*. (Assume that $n$ is a fixed integer that is greater than 1.).

I searched online and found that "strictly increasing" means $a > b$ compared to "increasing" meaning $a \geq b$, but I'm not sure how this relates to the statement.

Comment: "Strictly" means that $1$ and $\sqrt n$ are not included. For example, $3$ is between $1$ and $3$ but is not strictly between $1$ and $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Strictly" means that $1$ and $√n$ are not included. For example, $3$ is between $1$ and $3$ but is not strictly between $1$ and  $3$

It relates to this statement because it's excluding the case where they are equal.

Comment: Does that mean that "$n$ is not divisible by any prime number between 1 and $\sqrt{n}$ *strictly*" is a necessary condition for a number to be prime, but not a sufficient one in that $\sqrt{n}$ could still be divisible by the number? e.g. 9 is divisible by 3

Comment: $9$ is not a prime number. @Jacko

Comment: Yes, I know that. Maybe I'm confused, but is the statement "if $n$ is not divisible by any prime number between 1 and $\sqrt{n}$ *strictly* then $n$ is prime", false because of cases similar to 9 and $\sqrt{9}$?

Comment: You can't use the number $9$. "If $n$ is a prime" means that $n$ is a prime. $9$ is not a prime so you cannot use this example!

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about the converse: "If $n$ is not divisible by any prime number between 1 and $\sqrt{n}$ *strictly* then $n$ is prime."

Comment: A prime number $p$ is only divisible by $1$ and $p$. Figure it out. @Jacko

Here's a hint: Are you using the terminology correctly? If your converse was true, then a prime $p$ wouldn't be divisible by $1$.

If my answer helped, click the up-arrow next to my answer. If it solved your problem, click the checkmark.

Comment: it is evident that if $n$ is prime, it is divisible only by 1 and
himself,  in particular $n$ is not divisible by any prime $p$,
$1<p<\sqrt{n}$. But the interest is whether $n$ is prime or not,
so the Sieve of Eratosthenes  (Crible d'Ératosthène) say:   if
for any prime $p, \;2\leq p\leq\sqrt{n}$, $p$ not dives $n$ then
$n$ is  prime.

Comment: "If your converse was true, then a prime $p$ wouldn't be divisible by $1$." But you just said strictly means that 1 and $\sqrt{n}$ are not included? The converse doesn't include $1$ as being not divisible by the use of strictly? I was wondering whether saying strictly with $\sqrt{n}$ makes the converse false.

Comment: @Jacko You just edited your comment to add the word "strictly", and you are making me run in circles. I'm not helping you anymore.

Comment: That's very childish of you to say. I didn't edit it; I had just copied and pasted what I wrote from the original. You misread it and you haven't understood any of my other comments thus far.

Comment: @m.idaya what do you think of my comments?

Comment: Jossie Calderon:  for signification words, your reply and the third comment is
correct, but mathematically speaking, the statement in the text of
the question and your first two comments have no sense. thank you